# Swap Misplaced cells in R?

Tags: r

I have a huge database (more than 65M of rows) and I noticed that some cells are misplaced. As an example, let's say I have this:

```
library("tidyverse")

DATA <- tribble(
  ~SURNAME,~NAME,~STATE,~COUNTRY,
  'Smith','Emma','California','USA',
  'Johnson','Oliia','Texas','USA',
  'Williams','James','USA','California',
  'Jones','Noah','Pennsylvania','USA',
  'Williams','Liam','Illinois','USA',
  'Brown','Sophia','USA','Louisiana',
  'Daves','Evelyn','USA','Oregon',
  'Miller','Jacob','New Mexico','USA',
  'Williams','Lucas','Connecticut','USA',
  'Daves','John','California','USA',
  'Jones','Carl','USA','Illinois'
)
```

=====

```
> DATA
# A tibble: 11 x 4
   SURNAME  NAME   STATE        COUNTRY   
   <chr>    <chr>  <chr>        <chr>     
 1 Smith    Emma   California   USA       
 2 Johnson  Oliia  Texas        USA       
 3 Williams James  USA          California
 4 Jones    Noah   Pennsylvania USA       
 5 Williams Liam   Illinois     USA       
 6 Brown    Sophia USA          Louisiana 
 7 Daves    Evelyn USA          Oregon    
 8 Miller   Jacob  New Mexico   USA       
 9 Williams Lucas  Connecticut  USA       
10 Daves    John   California   USA       
11 Jones    Carl   USA          Illinois
```

As you can see, the Country and State are misplaced in some rows, how can I efficiently swap those ones?

Kind Regards,
Luiz.

Comment: do you have exhaustive correct list of state and countries?

Comment: How do you identify the rows where you need to do a Swap?

Comment: I am sorry, I used country as just a reference for my problem, my mistake. The real column is not associated with Country Names. But I will check all the answers so far and see how I can make good use of them.

Comment: @LuizJunior Next time please post your example that can reasonably represent your real-world data. All the answers tried to address this question assuming the country or state names are in certain format. Some even tried to find built-in dataset or package to have a list of state or country name. But it seems like you don't care about any country or state names because they are not in your data.

Comment: I am really sorry, the actual Data is not in English, I could translate but I was afraid it would not be clear enough, so I create a new example. Did it wrong. My appologies.

Comment: Btw, nothing here it is going to waste, I am sure of this, I am really learning with all of this, I am using all those functions and answers to lear, solve my problems and recreate new solutions with new things that I learn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `data.table` and the in-built `state.name` vector:

```
setDT(DATA)
DATA[COUNTRY %in% state.name, `:=`(COUNTRY = STATE, STATE = COUNTRY)]

DATA
#      SURNAME   NAME        STATE COUNTRY
#  1:    Smith   Emma   California     USA
#  2:  Johnson  Oliia        Texas     USA
#  3: Williams  James   California     USA
#  4:    Jones   Noah Pennsylvania     USA
#  5: Williams   Liam     Illinois     USA
#  6:    Brown Sophia    Louisiana     USA
#  7:    Daves Evelyn       Oregon     USA
#  8:   Miller  Jacob   New Mexico     USA
#  9: Williams  Lucas  Connecticut     USA
# 10:    Daves   John   California     USA
# 11:    Jones   Carl     Illinois     USA
```

Comment: Upvote for the nice `data.table` solution, although there could be STATE names that are not in the US.

Comment: Nevermind. The OP said country and state are just examples and they are not in the real-world dataset. So your post is a great example to show how to swap column values.

Comment: It works great! Thank You! I just had to replaced the state.name for the actual word in my DB, like USA here.

Answer (score 1):

Check this solution (it assumes that `COUNTRY` column is in ISO3 format e.g. MEX, CAN):

```
DATA %>%
  mutate(
    COUNTRY_TMP = if_else(str_detect(COUNTRY, '[A-Z]{3}'), COUNTRY, STATE),
    STATE = if_else(str_detect(COUNTRY, '[A-Z]{3}'), STATE, COUNTRY),
    COUNTRY = COUNTRY_TMP
  ) %>%
  select(-COUNTRY_TMP)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all country names are followed ISO3 format, we can first install the `countrycode` package. In this package, there is a data frame called `codelist` with a column `iso3c` with the ISO3 country names. We can use that as follows to swap the country name.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(countrycode)

DATA2 <- DATA %>%
  mutate(STATE2 = ifelse(STATE %in% codelist$iso3c & 
                           !COUNTRY %in% codelist$iso3c, COUNTRY, STATE),
         COUNTRY2 = ifelse(!STATE %in% codelist$iso3c & 
                             COUNTRY %in% codelist$iso3c, COUNTRY, STATE)) %>%
  select(-STATE, -COUNTRY) %>%
  rename(STATE = STATE2, COUNTRY = COUNTRY2)

DATA2
# # A tibble: 11 x 4
#    SURNAME  NAME   STATE        COUNTRY
#    <chr>    <chr>  <chr>        <chr>  
#  1 Smith    Emma   California   USA    
#  2 Johnson  Oliia  Texas        USA    
#  3 Williams James  California   USA    
#  4 Jones    Noah   Pennsylvania USA    
#  5 Williams Liam   Illinois     USA    
#  6 Brown    Sophia Louisiana    USA    
#  7 Daves    Evelyn Oregon       USA    
#  8 Miller   Jacob  New Mexico   USA    
#  9 Williams Lucas  Connecticut  USA    
# 10 Daves    John   California   USA    
# 11 Jones    Carl   Illinois     USA
```